# Plot.ly move y_title from overlapping with subplot yaxis_title and yaxis2_title

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

Is it possible to configure plot.ly to stop the y axis titles and subplot titles from overlapping?

[image]

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots



max_y_counts = 400
max_y_month_counts = 60



fig = make_subplots(
    rows=2, cols=1,
    shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.08,
    row_heights=[3,1],
    y_title="__________Y Title__________",
)

fig.update_xaxes(range=["2020-01-01", "2020-07-01"], row=1, col=1)
fig.update_xaxes(range=["2020-01-01", "2020-07-01"], row=2, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, max_y_counts], row=1, col=1)
fig.update_yaxes(range=[0, max_y_month_counts], row=2, col=1)



for row_max_y in [[1, max_y_counts], [2, max_y_month_counts]]:
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=["2020-06-01", "2020-06-01"],
            y=[0, row_max_y[1]],
            mode="lines",
            line=dict(color="#ac231b"),
        ),
        row=row_max_y[0], col=1,
        secondary_y=False,
    )


def merge (dict1, dict2):
    merged = dict1.copy()
    merged.update(dict2)
    return merged


# Define axis_style
def axis_style (**kwargs):
    return merge(dict(zeroline=False, showline=True, mirror=True), kwargs)


# Add labels to vertical event lines
# Specify layout style
layout = dict(
    width=750, height=600,
    xaxis=axis_style(),
    showlegend=False,
    xaxis_title="",
    yaxis=axis_style(
        title=dict(
            text="_____Y-Axis 1_____", standoff=0,
        )
    ),
    yaxis2=axis_style(title="_____Y-Axis 2_____"),
    # margin=dict(l=100,)
)


fig.update_layout(layout)

fig.write_html("first_figure.html", auto_open=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to correct the default value for the title of the y-axis for the entire graph, so I will update your layout. I changed the default value from -40 to -60.

```
layout = dict(
    width=750, height=600,
    xaxis=axis_style(),
    showlegend=False,
    xaxis_title="",
    yaxis=axis_style(
        title=dict(
            text="_____Y-Axis 1_____", standoff=0,
        )
    ),
    yaxis2=axis_style(title="_____Y-Axis 2_____"),
    # margin=dict(l=100,)
)
layout.update(annotations=[dict(xshift=-60)])

fig.update_layout(layout)
```

[image]